# Pandas GroupBy - Applying function to each group while preserving original order

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to apply a function that returns a Series of the same length as a DataFrame, to each group in a DataFrame while preserving the original order of indices.

Here's a toy DataFrame which I'll use to give an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2),columns=['x1','x2'])
>>> df['group'] = np.random.choice(list('ABC'),size=10)
>>> df
         x1        x2 group
0  0.710005  0.632971     C
1  0.384604  0.417906     C
2  0.307053  0.869622     C
3  0.699528  0.026040     A
4  0.773514  0.391718     C
5  0.602334  0.936036     C
6  0.872275  0.162393     C
7  0.641256  0.147996     B
8  0.047188  0.358093     C
9  0.059955  0.353174     B
```

It's easy enough to apply a function which only depends on **one** column and get back a single sorted Series. For example:

```
>>> df.groupby('group')['x1'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.mean())/x.std())
0    0.618951
1   -0.488499
2   -0.752430
3         NaN
4    0.835095
5    0.252510
6    1.171211
7    0.707107
8   -1.636838
9   -0.707107
```

However, if the function depends on multiple columns, the result is a multi-indexed Series that does not preserve order:

```
>>> df.groupby('group').apply(lambda grp: grp['x1']/grp['x2'].mean())
group   
A      3    26.863693
B      7     2.559033
       9     0.239262
C      0     1.318752
       1     0.714357
       2     0.570315
       4     1.436714
       5     1.118766
       6     1.620150
       8     0.087646
```

When the desired output is instead this:

```
>>> res = []
>>> for idx, grp in df.groupby('group'):
...     res.append(grp['x1'] / grp['x2'].mean())
... 
>>> pd.concat(res).sort_index()
0     1.318752
1     0.714357
2     0.570315
3    26.863693
4     1.436714
5     1.118766
6     1.620150
7     2.559033
8     0.087646
9     0.239262
```

This loop + concat accomplishes what is needed, just wondering if there's a more elegant way using `apply`.

Comment: `df['x1'] / df.groupby('group')['x2'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you need `apply` here, but always we could use [`Series.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) at the end:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda grp: grp['x1']/grp['x2'].mean()).sort_index(level = 1)
group   
B      0    0.946438
C      1    2.273879
A      2    0.167197
       3    1.378490
C      4    0.320788
       5    0.085125
A      6    1.165615
B      7    1.622586
C      8    1.763416
       9    1.817172
Name: x1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This should do it, though to get the exact desired output the 1st element of the multiindex should be dropped. Apply isn't needed in this specific example but in cases where the function is more complicated it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Method from `transform`

```
g=df.groupby('group')
s=(df-g.transform('mean'))/g.transform('std')
Out[33]: 
  group        x1        x2
0   NaN  0.618951  0.332083
1   NaN -0.488498 -0.423041
2   NaN -0.752430  1.162998
3   NaN       NaN       NaN
4   NaN  0.835094 -0.514991
5   NaN  0.252511  1.396187
6   NaN  1.171211 -1.320183
7   NaN  0.707107 -0.707107
8   NaN -1.636838 -0.633053
9   NaN -0.707107  0.707107
s=s.dropna(axis=1)
```